# get the size of heap array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

Code1:

```
int * a;
a=new int[222];
cout<<"the size of a is "<<sizeof(a)<<endl;
```

Output1:

```
the size of a is 8
```

Code2:

```
int * a;
a=new int[222];
cout<<"the size of a is "<<a.length()<<endl;
```

Output2:

```
error: member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or
  union
```

How to get the size of a heap array? Thanks..

Comment: Use `std::vector`. Much easier to use and less prone to memory leaks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is, it can't be done, at least not in a portable manner.  You'll need to keep track of the array's size separately somehow (e.g. in an integer variable or similar).

Answer (score 4):

Use a container instead of a raw pointer:

```
std::vector<int> a(222);
cout << "the size of a is " << a.size(); << endl;
```